# Sql Server: altering a view makes clustered and full-text search indexes to be deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, indexing, full-text-search

**Scenario**

I have got two tables: `tblA` and `tblB`, with the same structure. Every moment, one of them is online, and the other one is in stand by. Periodically data are updated in the stand by table, it goes online and the other one goes in stand by.

This procedure cannot be modified.

There is a trivial view that accesses the tables. Let's say `vw`:

```
create view vw as      
select * from tblA
go
```

When the tables switch, the view is altered:

```
alter view vw as
select * from tblB
go
```

**Issue**

Now I have to create a full-text index on the view. No problem in creating the index.
But when I alter the view, the index is deleted.

I figure out that I have to recreate the full-text index every time I alter the table. But I wonder whether another solution exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to all views, including standard indexed views. It is annoying.

From [ALTER VIEW](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) docs

> ALTER VIEW can be applied to indexed views; however, ALTER VIEW unconditionally drops all indexes on the view.

No workaround exists: you have to recreate the view index or index the base table.

Comment: Sad. I feared that. But I hoped that some 'disable indexes-alter view-enable indexes-rebuild catalog' sequence could be possible.